# How to Validate DOS Batch User Input From Prompt

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, dos

I'm trying to write a script that prompts the user for a drive letter and then validate the entry insofar that it is a single character and falls within a valid range: D-Z

This is what I have so far:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set MIN_DRIVE_LOWER=d
set MAX_DRIVE_LOWER=z
set /P RELEASE_DRIVE="What is the assigned network drive letter on this workstation? "
echo Release drive is %RELEASE_DRIVE%
if /I !RELEASE_DRIVE! GEQ %MIN_DRIVE_LOWER% (
  if /I !RELEASE_DRIVE! LEQ %MAX_DRIVE_LOWER% (
    echo Release drive is lower-case.
  )
)
```

No matter what I enter at the prompt my script reaches the "`echo Release drive is lower-case.`"  Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure, you want that `/I`?

Comment: @Stephan  I don't know how to fix this.  That's why I'm posting here.

Comment: when I interpret your code right, you want to test, if the user did input an upper- or lowercase letter. `/i` tells `if` to ignore capitalization.

Comment: @Stephan That's just part of it.  In the end, I want to validate the input by verifying that the user entered only a single character, D-Z.  If they entered a valid lower-case character, I want to just convert it to upper-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hacksy alternative.  Rather than giving the user the freedom to screw up then punishing him for his insolence, you can enforce entry of a valid response with the `choice` command.  Then to avoid a long list of `if errorlevel` conditions to convert the choice back to its alpha value, there's a trick using a special environment variable that converts ERRORLEVEL to an alphanumeric character, `%=ExitCodeAscii%`.  [More details are here.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

```js
@echo off
setlocal

choice /c defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz /n /m "What is the assigned network drive letter on this workstation? "
set /a ascii = %ERRORLEVEL% + 67
cmd /c exit /b %ascii%
set "letter=%=ExitCodeAscii%"

echo You chose %letter%
```

It's not clear what your goal is, whether the drive letter you want chosen is an existing letter or an unused letter for a drive mapping.  Depending on your intentions, you might be interested in one or both of the following tips.  *shrug*

You can programmatically determine what drive letters are currently assigned with a WMI query using `wmic`:

```js
wmic logicaldisk get deviceid /value | find "="
```

If you want to create a network drive mapping and would like to allow Windows to figure out which drive letter to assign automatically, use `pushd`.

```js
net use \\server /user:domain\username password
pushd \\server\share
```

... then to remove the mapping:

```js
popd
net use \\server /delete
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the ninja tip!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /P rd="What is the assigned network drive letter on this workstation? "
echo Release drive is %rd%

:: Variable valid will be either 0 or 1
set valid=0
for %%a in (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
  if /i "%rd%"=="%%a" (
    set valid=1
    if "%rd%" neq "%%a" set rd=%%a
  )
)
Echo.

if "%valid%"=="1" (
Echo Valid Input Detected: %rd%
) else (
Echo Invalid Input: %rd%
)
pause
```

**Edit:** I made it so that it converted the character to upper-case too.

Comment: How would the line `if "%rd%" neq "%%a" set rd=%%a` make any difference, since it's in the scope of the `if` statement two lines above it?

Comment: @JimFell: for conversion to upper case. It's parsed (for example) as: `if "d" neq "D" set rd=D`. A bit redundant, just `set rd=%%A` would do.